# Can't use utf8 encoding with datatool

Tags: tables, font-encodings, input-encodings, datatool

I am using datatool to manage tables and I am getting errors when the `data.csv` file (encoded either as UTF-8 or ANSI) has characters like 'á'. I can get it around by having `data.csv` encoded as ANSI and using `{\'a}`, but that is too boring to do. The interesting thing is, if I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, I can encode `data.csv` as UTF-8 and use chars like 'á' without problems, but the font looks damn ugly.

`file.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
á é õ ç {\c{c}} {\~a}
\begin{table}
    \DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}
    \DTLdisplaydb{data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

`data.csv`

```
a,e
a,c
```

`data.csv`

```
{'/a},{'/e}
{\~a},{\c{c}}
```

`data.csv`

```
á,é
ã,ç
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample of `data.csv`?

Comment: Using `\DTLloaddb[headers={á,é}]{data}{data.csv}` and setting the first line of `data.csv` to `,` (yes, one comma) loads everything just fine.

Comment: wow weirdly that works

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel's fix works! *sneaky edit*...

Comment: @Silex _re-edit_ ;) @Fernando This seems to be only an issue with the headers (i.e. the first line of the `.csv`) where `datatool` seems to applying some TeX-foo that can't handle accented characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the following solutions:

1. *From my comment*:

   - Replace the first line of your `.csv` with: `,`
   - Add the headings to the `\DTLloaddb` command:

     ```
     \DTLloaddb[headers={á,é}]{data}{data.csv}
     ```
2. **Use [`lmodern`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) with the T1 font encoding.** (recommended)
3. Taking a look in `T1.enc`<sup>a)</sup> we can find the following lines:

   ```
   \DeclareTextAccent{\'}{T1}{1}
   % … and much later …
   \DeclareTextComposite{\'}{T1}{a}{225}
   \DeclareTextComposite{\'}{T1}{e}{233}
   ```

   If we try to copy this for the OT1 encoding we don't get any single char *(but it compiles!),* because there isn't any glyph at position 225 (E1<sub>16</sub>) or 233 (E9<sub>16</sub>) in [the OT1 font encoding](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/ot1.htm) but they are in fact in [the T1 font encoding](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/t1.htm).

   What TeX actually does when you use `\'e`:
   It sets the special accent glyph at 13<sub>16</sub> (19<sub>10</sub>/`´`) over 65<sub>16</sub> (101<sub>10</sub>/`e`). Try it yourself:

   ```
   \accent19 e
   ```

   As TeX knows that this is a special accent glyph it can set it correct over capital letters. But let's let the TeXbook<sup>b)</sup> (which didn't exactly used OT1 but a font encoding with “quite” the same layout<sup>c)</sup>) speak for itself:

   > Appendix B shows that plain TeX handles most of the accents by using TeX's `\accent` primitive. For example, `\'#1` is equivalent to `{\accent19 #1}`, where
   >   `#1` is the argument being accented. The general rule is that `\accent<number>` puts an
   >   accent over the next character; the `<number>` tells where that accent appears in the
   >   current font.

   And regarding capital letters:

   > The accent is assumed to be properly positioned for a character whose
   >   height equals the x-height of the current font; taller or shorter characters cause the
   >   accent to be raised or lowered, taking due account of the slantedness of the fonts of
   >   accenter and accentee.

   ---

   Line 696 of `plain.tex` looks like this:

   ```
   \def\'#1{{\accent19 #1}}
   ```

---

<sup>a)</sup> <sub>`texmf/tex/latex/base/T1.enc`</sub>
<sup>b)</sup> <sub>`texmf/doc/knuth/texbook.tex.gz`</sub>
<sup>c)</sup> <sub>One can read on that more in [`texmf/doc/latex/base/encguide.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/encguide.pdf):</sub>

> <sub>Little attention was paid to font encodings prior to the arrival of TeX 3. Up to
>   that time, one used Donald Knuth’s fonts (the Computer Modern family, using the encodings we now refer to as `OT1` and the `OM` series), or one was on one’s own.</sub>
>
> <sub>The Computer Modern text encoding raises problems in unmodiﬁed TeX, because hyphenation cannot break words containing `\accent` commands. Even in those Western European languages for which the `OT1` encoding has symbols for the necessary `\accent`-based diacritics, this shortcoming ruins typesetting of running text.</sub>

Comment: The guess is almost wrong. :) What LaTeX does with `\'e` does not depend on UTF-8 being used or not; if T1 is the font encoding the instruction `\'e` is translated into the command "print the character at position 233 in the current font"; with OT1 it resolves to `\accent19 e`.

Comment: @egreg Better now?

Comment: Very good; I'd add only that OT1 encoded fonts (in LaTeX-speak) use (quite) the same layout as the one explained in the TeXbook.

Answer (score 2):

Using `fontenc` and encoding your data as UTF-8 seems like your best bet. If you don't like the font you can load a package with a font you do like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datatool,tgbonum}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
á é õ ç {\c{c}} {\~a}
\begin{table}
    \DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}
    \DTLdisplaydb{data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: result]

You can pick a font from the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: The problem is not the font itself but the fact that it is not "vectorized"

Comment: How do you mean 'not vectorized'?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I have the same problem, but i solve this with two simple lines..

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I don need any "," or special symbol in my csv file.
I leave an example of my files on this link. for those who can be useful.

[Example of datatool recognizing accents](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hajkpd09q7zpwvq/AACEp4gnM7Mb39xsT2MYq6Wka?dl=0)